# JavaScript addEvent function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an `addEvent` function:

```
function addEvent(elem, event, func ) {
   if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined')
        elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
   else 
       elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
}

<a href="#" id="link">link</a>
```

and I'm trying to add the following to `window.onload`:

```
addEvent(window, 'load', function (){
   // add another event
   var link= document.getElementById('link');
   addEvent(link, 'click', function () {alert('Hi'); });
});
```

My question is: why does the `link` event not work?

Comment: You shouldn't test for an unrelated property (`window.event`).  Instead, check for `addEventListener` itself.

Comment: trye using document. i don't think the window hase a onload. Plus try jquery..

Answer (score 4):

You misspelled `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function attachEvent(element, event, callbackFunction) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, callbackFunction, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, callbackFunction);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof (window.event) != 'undefined'
```

doesn't work really on chrome when I tested your code!
this would be work fine:

```
!!window.attachEvent
```

and i consider that using brace in `if..esle` is a good practice.

```
function addEvent(elem, event, func ) {
    if (!!window.attachEvent){

        elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
    }
    else{
       elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working this way, try this:

```
Element.prototype.events = {};
Element.prototype.addEvent = function (event, callBack) {
    if (this.events["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))] == undefined) {
        this.events["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))] = [];
    }
    this.events["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))].push(callBack);
    if (this["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))] == undefined) {
        this["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))] = function (e) {
            for (i in this.events["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))]) {
                this.events["on" + (event.replace("on", ""))][i](e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will use it this way:

```
document.body.addEvent("click",function(){
   alert("Test");
});
document.body.addEvent("click",function(){
   alert("Test 2");
});
document.getElemntById("inputtest").addEvent("keyup",function(){
   alert("Input keyup");
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try this.

```
function addEvent(elem,event,func)
{
    var evn = "on"+event;
    elem[evn] = func;
}
var obj = document.getElementById("link");
addEvent(obj,"click",function(){alert('hi');});
```

Here using this code you need not worry about attachEvent or addEventListener. This code will work for all browser. Hope this solves your problem.